# location access checkbox end activity after checkbox is checked

Tags: android

i have an activity that uses GPS tracking but when the GPS satellite option in the set up is not check my activity automatically opens the window and lets you check the check box my problem here is i want to end the said window when the user checks the checkbox!i've added a photo to make it easier to understand what i mean.[image]

Comment: You can't. It's an Android activity, you cannot interact with it this way.

Comment: thank you i didnt know that its not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defiantly you cannot close this screen because it's not in your application.

Instead, you can let user close it by click on Back button and you check its status another time in onResume() method of your activity.